# update partialview after post - jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have ascx file named searchResultPlayer.
In view i rendered the above ascx file using following code

```
<div id="player">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("SearchResultPlayer"); %>
  </div>
```

I am using following jquery code to post .

```
 $('#resultTable tr').live('click', function (event) {
 $.post("/Search/SearchResult", {
             content: "GetCallDetails"
         }
         );
  });
```

Post is working fine. From the controller I am returning a partialview.Code is shown below

```
 return PartialView("SearchResutPlayer", searchModel); .
```

the controller returning this after each post.I can see that while debugging.

My question is how can i update the returned value in the view using jquery?.

I know i can use something like this

```
 <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Search", 
                        new AjaxOptions {                              
                           HttpMethod="POST",
                           UpdateTargetId="player",                             
                        })) { %> }
```

But because of some problem i cant use ajax begin form. So in jquery is there anything like UpdateTargetId???

**EDIT**

I tried the method suggested by Darin.
I write jquery like this

```
                    $('#player').load(
                 '<%= Url.Action("SearchResult", "Search") %>',
                 { content: 'GetCallDetails' }
             );
```

In **View**

```
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         {
             if (content != null)                

             {
                 searchModel.selectedRecord = "test message";
                 return PartialView("SearchResutPlayer", searchModel);
             }
         }
```

And in **ascx file**

```
 <label> <%= Html.Encode(Model.selectedRecord) %></label>
```

Initially the Model.selected have a value like' loaded' . But after ajax post its not changing to 'test message'

I tried method suggested by PsychoCoder too.But thats also not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But because of some problem i cant use ajax begin form.

A problem? I wouldn't call this exactly a *problem*. I would call it good design. You are a happy man if you cannot use `Ajax.*` helpers. Personally I hate those helpers as they turn your markup into a pollution and that's especially true for MVC 1 and 2.

So in jQuery you have the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function which allows you to set the html of a given element:

```
$('#resultTable tr').live('click', function (event) {
    $.post(
        '<%= Url.Action("SearchResult", "Search") %>', 
        { content: 'GetCallDetails' }, 
        function(result) {
            $('#player').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

or even easier with the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$('#resultTable tr').live('click', function (event) {
    $('#player').load(
        '<%= Url.Action("SearchResult", "Search") %>', 
        { content: 'GetCallDetails' }
    );
});
```

Also notice the usage of an url helper instead of hardcoding the url. You should always be using url helpers when dealing with urls because there are hundredths of questions on StackOverflow going like *My application stops working when deployed in IIS* and I just don't want one more :-)

Comment: hi.thanx for help. i tried the both method u suggest. But its not replacing the searchresultplayer.ascx file. When using htmlhelper i can debug that ascx file. But when using jquery the break points on ascx file is not working and its not replacing the current data.. Is i need to use ascx file to reload some partial part of page?

Comment: @Null Pointer, what does your `/Search/SearchResult` controller action returns? Normally it should return the partial, like this `return PartialView("searchresultplayer");`.

Comment: @Null Pointer, in your edited example you are calling the `.load` function multiple times. Look more careful at my answer: the `.load` function is invoked only once inside a `.live` callback. In your case the first load sends a GET request as you are not passing any parameters and the second AJAX request will probably erase any data that the first request might have put in the `#player` div.

Comment: I think ajax succes event is not firing

Comment: @Darin.Thank you so much. There wassome problem with my ascx file.Thats why i didnt get result.Thanks again

Comment: @Ben, of course that it doesn't work. .js is a static file. There's no server side helpers or whatever in static files.